# Web browser jumps to particular H1/div on website

Tags: html, css

Right...

I am working on a client's website and so far most of it is working well.. until today...

The URL: http://www.chris-loweth.co.uk/shoaib-hassan-photography/site_demo_1/

When the page displays it is jumping to a `H1` on the page that is half way down the page...

There are a few `<a href="#">` links for dummy content but these shouldn't be working like scroll anchors... and there's definitely not an anchor in the div that the browser seems to be scrolling down to...

Spent hours on this and wondered if some fresh eyes might help...

I've tried to validate the markup but as this is a test site some of the div IDs duplicate so validation fails.

Thank you guys n gals!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's jumping to the `H1`. I think it's this line near the top of your `tools.js` file that is doing it:

```
$('input[type="text"]:first').focus();
```

It is scrolling to put this in view, and depending on your browser size, this could well put the `H1` above at the top of the window.

Comment: Oh I am such a tool. I'm just waiting for the timer let me accept the answer...

What a wally.

Thanks @David M

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by this line in the javascript file:

```
// Set focus to event title on page load
$('input[type="text"]:first').focus();
```

The first input field is way down on the page. Setting the focus to it is causing the browser to scroll to the input field instead of remaining at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Siver - I think you replied almost exactly the same time... thank you though!